# Como implementar o padrão DAO em subclasses?

Tags: java, herança, padrão-dao

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que se trata de uma loja de armas.
Possuo a classe `Produto` com as subclasses `Arma`, `Faca` e `Municao`. Neste projeto estou aplicando o padrão DAO, porém não entendi muito bem como funciona a sua aplicação em subclasses.

Possuo a classe `ProdutoDAO`:

```
public class ProdutoDAO implements GenericDAO<Produto> {

    Connection connection = null;

    @Override
    public void save(Produto produto) throws SQLException {
        try {
            connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUTO(ID, ID_MARCA, DESCRICAO,"
                    + "PESO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"    ;
            PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstm.setInt(1, produto.getId());
            pstm.setString(2, produto.getDescricao());
            pstm.setDouble(3, produto.getPeso());
            pstm.execute();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao inserir o produto no "
                    + "banco de dados." + sqle.getMessage());
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Ocorreu um erro. Contate o suporte.\n" + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

A minha dúvida é em relação à classe `ArmaDAO`. Como devo implementá-la?
Ela deve estender a classe `ProdutoDAO`? A classe `ProdutoDAO` deve ser abstrata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O padrão DAO é uma maneira de separar sua camada de persistência de dados das demais camadas. Entendo que organização pode ser feita da maneira que achar melhor.

Não me preocuparia em fazer nenhum tipo de herança entre estas classes. O assunto é [extenso](https://codeburst.io/inheritance-is-evil-stop-using-it-6c4f1caf5117), mas herança é algo que precisa mais ser evitado do que usado.

Com isto em mente, considere criar um `ArmaDAO` separado. Se precisar algo do `ProdutoDAO`, considere usar ele dentro do `ArmaDAO` usando **[composição e não herança](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354/2387977)**. Você não mencionou se está usando algum mecanismo de injeção de dependência, mas sua classe poderia ficar assim:

```
public class ArmaDAO implements GenericDAO<Arma> {

    @Autowired
    private ProdutoDAO produtoDAO; //usando ProdutoDAO dentro de ArmaDAO, sem herança, com composição

    public void salvarArma(Arma arma) {
         Produto produto = produtoDAO.buscar(); // buscar do ProdutoDAO
         // cria conexão e busca/salvar algo de Arma
    }
```

E sua classe ProdutoDAO continuaria basicamente como está.